# Product matrix and induction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant, matrix-equations

I am not sure which method to use here.
Should I do it for $n=2$ and $n=3$ and then use induction on $n$?

Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n \in \mathbb{R}$, where $n \geq 2$.
Show that 
$$\left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & \alpha_1 & \alpha_1^2 & \cdots & \alpha_1^{n-1}\\
1 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_2^2 & \cdots & \alpha_2^{n-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &  \vdots\\
1 & \alpha_n & \alpha_n^2 & \cdots & \alpha_n^{n-1}
\end{array} \right| = \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}(\alpha_j-\alpha_i).$$

Comment: [This is Vandermonde matrix.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to see that Warwick are still using this [question](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/undergrad/ughandbook/lecturers/ma106/sheet7.pdf) (link is broken now).
In my year most people heard through others that this is called the Vandermonde matrix, and a [bunch of proofs](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant) for it are found online. I realise that the deadline is today, but do attempt to understand the proofs.

I found the first proof the easiest to understand at the time, but perhaps you'd like to use the second proof to help with your induction.

Good luck!

Comment: It is a nice question. They gave us a hint for induction proof which is what I've done, was also interested in alternative proofs. When were you at Warwick?

Comment: @NeoXx Yeah, that's what was motivated during the question, but I personally found it a bit too beat-around-the-bush for my liking and submitted a different proof. And I'm still at Warwick as a lowly second year!

Comment: It wasn't a proof which I found intuitive. The first one is easier to understand. Btw I kind of started this year on the wrong foot and I'm lagging behind on some modules (haven't gotten a good understanding of a few of them from term 1 and can't say that I'm on top of my work in term 2 neither). The easter holiday is coming and I was wondering what is a good way to revise all the modules for exams, should I do lots of past papers as in A-level and then see what I don't know? I am not sure I have time to go through all the lecture notes from every module. How did you revise last year?

Comment: @NeoXx That's typical of a first year student and isn't anything to worry about really. It really is a question of WHEN you'll fall behind during term, rather than IF you'll fall behind. It really depends on the module that you're studying for. e.g. for MA134 you should do as many questions as you can and go through the screencasts again if you need to. It's an applied module so you won't need to be able to reprove theorems. Last year some joke questions were thrown in that were worth marks (which you can see for yourself). For Analysis II you should definitely be able to prove and apply.